# What is the yoga of Sri VallalAr?

Tags: life, saint, shaiva-siddhanta

He was (is?) a well known divine figure of the south Indian shaiva siddha tradition.

His name was Sri RAmalinga swamigal and lived in tamil nadu.

It is believed that he DEMATERIALIZED his physical body and transformed it to a light body. Thus attained immortality.

His place vaDalur is a pilgrim place.

What is the yoga which was done and propagated by him ?

Comment: It is next to impossible to know about the methods of a Yogi/saint.  Whatever may be the practice, if he/she attained siddhi means, it indicates their greatness.  @Rakesh Joshi

Comment: @srimannarayanakv impossible for illiterates who dont have knowledge of scriptures and dharma. Most of the saints have given out their teachings in form of verbal discourse and books etc. Their teaching and practices are upheld by thier disciples.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I ll try to find best verses from his writings called "Thiruvarutpa" ... Vallalars experience he wrote in that book and also method for his "deathless education". Deathless education term he used it in his book. So I will find proper verses and soon ll write the answer

Comment: I agree that most of the saints hinted out at the deep spiritual knowledge but never the methods.  The same method can't be applied to everyone.  @Rakesh Joshi

Comment: @srimannarayanakv first you said can't be known. Then you say can't be applied.  Better decide which one you mean to say ?

Comment: Both are correct.  What I said earlier  was about the core method,  which can't be the same for all people. :-)@Rakesh Joshi

Comment: An accomplished Guru will adopt different methods for different disciples, depending upon their karma, capacity, maturity .@Rakesh Joshi

Comment: @srimannarayanakv who says so ? Do you mean that a guru from sri vaishnava line will adopt shaiva or shakta for different pupil  ? He can only initiate from the line he belongs to and thing which he is adept into. Nevertheless if he initiates multiple people in different practices we still can know many of practices followed by him through the pupil.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi: I think I did not communicate to you properly.  I am not talking about Mataadhipathis of Vaishnava or Shaiva or some other sect..  I am talking about an accomplished Guru like Sri Ramana Maharshi.  I thought Sri RAmalinga swamigal  is of that order.  The Gurus of that line will allow to practise in his/her method, duly assisting them in moving towards the Ultimate.  There can be multiple ways to reach the Ultimate.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv ramana has given his method of self enquiry in his talks.  You mean to say he did something else than this ?

Comment: For clarification purpose I will give names of 3 persons who came to Sri Ramana with different backgrounds.  1. Sri Ganapati muni (expert in vedas and mantra sastra ), 2. Sri Yogi Ramaiah  (performed Rama nama japa innumerable times ) and 3. Dr. Paul Brunton (agnostic with western bent of mind). Maharishi told the same self enquiry to all but hoe he  guided them is not known.  That is what I have been saying @Rakesh Joshi

Comment: @srimannarayanakv so you saying that all three were initiated into different things by him ? If so what paths ? Also if ramana had no guru. Is this okayed by shastras ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97323/discussion-between-srimannarayana-k-v-and-rakesh-joshi).

Comment: @mods please delete these messages